# Separate city name from address sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, street-address

I want to separate city name from the addresses in the Data base.

addresses are in different formats
e.g

```
835 street no.3  Jalabad D.I. Khan ................ here city name is D.I khan
Ho. No. 102 St. No. 85  RawalPindi   ..........here city name is RawalPindi
h no.944 St. No.74  Karkhana road Gujrat   ......here city name is Gujrat
Ho. no.241 S No.26  I-8/3 Isb              .........here city name is isb
```

I am doing this but it is only working for few... I need a general query which can work for every format of address

```
SELECT DISTINCT REVERSE
( 
  LEFT( REVERSE(All_Students.Address), CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(All_Students.Address))-1 ) 
) as Addresses
from All_Students
order by addresses
```

Comment: Is the format like last space character to the end of the word is the city.?

Comment: You should store all info in different table fiels [i.e. street, city, zipcode...].

Comment: Storing addresses in a single field is a big-no in SQL and a perfect anti-example of database normalization.

Comment: I added the SQL Server tag because this seems to be a SQL server query (`charindex`).

Comment: What makes a city in your strings? There is no dilimiter that you can use to split it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do we know about Cities in these address strings? City is in the end of the string but it can contain more than 1 word. So I think there is no way to formalize a method to cut a City name from the Address line using only this table.

I think the one way to do it is to find an universal City table for your area/country in the Internet for example in any format (ZIP codes, government statistics,...) and use this table to cut Cities from this table from the Address line.

**For MySQL**

```
SELECT TRIM(TRIM(TRAILING Cities.Name FROM Address) ), Cities.Name
from All_Students left join Cities 
     on All_Students.Address like CONCAT('% ',Cities.Name)
```

**For MS SQL Server**

```
SELECT LEFT(Address,LEN(Address)-LEN(Cities.Name)), Cities.Name
from All_Students left join Cities 
     on All_Students.Address like '% '+Cities.Name
```

**To update in MS SQL as required in the comment use this :**

```
UPDATE
    A
SET
    A.address = B.NewAddress,
    A.City = B.City
FROM
    Transformed_All_Student A
    JOIN
    (
      SELECT Student_id, 
             LEFT(Address,LEN(Address)-LEN(Cities.Name)) as NewAddress, 
             Cities.Name as City
      from All_Students left join Cities 
         on All_Students.Address like '% '+Cities.Name

    ) B 
ON A.Student_ID = B.Student_id
```

Comment: SELECT TRIM(TRIM(TRAILING Cities_lookup.Dirty_City_Name FROM Address) ), Cities_lookup.Dirty_City_Name
from Student left join Cities_lookup 
 on Student.Address like CONCAT('% ',Cities_lookup.Dirty_City_Name)

but it is not working
Cities_lookup is the name of my lookup table having all the possiblies of city names.
 it is also giving error on %

Comment: I've added MSSQL version of this query. Please use it.

Comment: how to use these results to update in another table's columns

i am doing this but its not working
update Transformed_All_Student 
SET Address=
 (
SELECT LEFT(Address,LEN(Address)-LEN(g.Dirty_City_name)) 
from All_Students p left join Cities_lookup  g
on p.Address like '% '+g.Dirty_City_name
WHERE p.Address IS NULL
)
where Address is null

Comment: How `Transformed_All_Student` table is related to  `All_Students`. Is there any common ID?

Comment: Student_ID is common column

Comment: I've added an UPDATE statement to my answer. If this answer worked for you, please [mark it as accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Comment: and id i want to update 2 columns??
i am having a Cities table in which one column is Name....(which i am extracting from address in above code) and other column is Standard_Name.....

now i want to cut city name from address and place the address in address table as you did it...and also the standard city name against extracted city name from the address in the transformed_All_Student table

Comment: address is going in the table but city name does not